# Gamma Integral with constant in exponent

Tags: calculus

If there is a constant, c, in the exponent of the Gamma integral $e^{-cx}$, how is the reflected in the gamma function? Is it something like $\frac{\Gamma(t)}{c^{2}}$ ?

$$\Gamma(t)=\int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-x}\,dx$$

Comment: Try a change of variable then integrate by parts. See what happens.

Comment: @Mattos Hello Mattos

Comment: Mine is one of three answers so far, but I'm the only one who's up-voted the question.  Sometimes that is neglected. $\qquad$

Comment: @Mattos : You really don't need to integrate by parts to answer the question as it is (currently?) phrased above.  See my answer below. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \overbrace{\int_0^\infty x^{t-1} e^{-cx}\,dx = \frac 1 {c^t} \int_0^\infty (cx)^{t-1} e^{-cx} (c\,dx)}^\text{First, grasp this first step. Then the rest is routine.} \\[12pt]
= {} & \frac 1 {c^t} \int_0^\infty u^{t-1} e^{-u}\,du = \frac 1 {c^t} \Gamma(t).
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Integral to solve

$$\int_0^{+\infty} x^{t-1}\ e^{-cx}\ \text{d}x$$

Set

$$y = cx ~~~~~~~ \text{d}y = c\ \text{d}x ~~~~~~~ x = \frac{y}{c}$$

Thence

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \left(\frac{y}{c}\right)^{t-1}\ e^{-y}\ \frac{\text{d}y}{c}$$

Arranging and you'll get

$$\frac{1}{c^t}\int_0^{+\infty}y^{t-1}\ e^{-y}\ \text{d}y$$

Namely

$$\frac{\Gamma[t]}{c^t}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^\infty dx\ x^{t-1}e^{-cx}=\frac{1}{c^t}\int_0^\infty ds\ s^{t-1}e^{-s} =\frac{1}{c^t}\Gamma(t).$$
(change variables to $s=cx$)